# How can Bluetooth be on even if my laptop is sleeping/s2idle?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, lenovo

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome,  on a 3rd gen thinkpad x1 yoga.

Due to Lenovos "creative" new BIOS, s3 sleep is not supported, so I'm forced to use s2idle with acpi.ec_no_wakeup=1 as a BIOS option (passed in grub config).

Just now I was pairing my headphones to my phone, and saw my laptop listed under "available Bluetooth devices," even though it's napping in my backpack below me.

How is that possible? In s2idle with the acpi option, it can easily sleep for days without needing a recharge, so it's not using that much power.